# How to specify order of how snippets are shown in YASnippet's prompt menu?

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

When writing snippets for YASnippet, is it possible to specify how snippets should be displayed in the prompt menu ("Choose a snippet: ..")?

For the sake of user friendliness, I would like the prompt menu to look like the Emacs YASnippet menu.

-Øyvind

**EDIT**: I've found a solution to my problem. Simply redefine *yas--prompt-for-template* in Emacs config file this way:

```
(defun yas--prompt-for-template (templates &optional prompt)
  (when templates
    (cl-some (lambda (fn)
               (funcall fn (or prompt "Choose a snippet: ")
                        templates
                        #'yas--template-name))
             yas-prompt-functions)))
```